# $\pi_1 (x,y) = x$ the projection function with $\pi_1 : R^2 \rightarrow R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\pi_1 (x,y) = x$ the projection function  with $\pi_1 : R^2 \rightarrow R$.

Im studying open and closed function, how can i determine if $\pi_1$ is an open function or a closed function ?

Comment: Take any open/closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard product topology and show that its image is again an open/closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ again with the standard topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Compute the projection of the closed set $\{(x,1/x)/x\in\mathbb{R}_+\}.$ Is it closed?

To show that it is open: Compute the projection of any open ball. Is it open? Any open set is the union of open balls. So, using the result for open balls, is the projection of an open set open?